# SQL view / query to join data between 2 tables via a json field

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, sql-server-json

Example table structure:

```
create table issues
(id int, title varchar(50), affectedclients varchar(max))

create table clients
(id int, name varchar(50))

insert into issues (id, title, affectedclients) values (1, 'Error when clicking save', '["1","2"]');
insert into issues (id, title, affectedclients) values (2, '404 error on url', '[3]');

insert into clients (id, name) values (1, 'Tesco');
insert into clients (id, name) values (2, 'Costa');
insert into clients (id, name) values (3, 'Boots');
insert into clients (id, name) values (4, 'Nandos');
```

I want to run a query so that I can get the data in the following format:

> ```
> Id   Title                        AffectedClients
> 1    Error when clicking save     Tesco, Costa
> 2    404 error on url             Boots
> ```

How can I achieve this please in the most performant way possible?

If this will be very easy with a properly normalized database then please provide an example.

Comment: Have a go and let us know where you get stuck...

Comment: I am stuck at creating a sql query that extracts the data in the format I mentioned above.

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: Its SQL Server 2016 but we can upgrade to 2017 / 2019

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `OPENJSON()` with explicit schema definition to parse the `JSON` text in the `affectedclients` column. After that you need to aggregate the names (using `FOR XML PATH` for SQL Server 2016+ or `STRING_AGG()` for SQL SQL Server 2017+).

Data:

```
create table issues
(id int, title varchar(50), affectedclients varchar(max))
create table clients
(id int, name varchar(50))
insert into issues (id, title, affectedclients) values (1, 'Error when clicking save', '["1","2"]');
insert into issues (id, title, affectedclients) values (2, '404 error on url', '[3]');
insert into clients (id, name) values (1, 'Tesco');
insert into clients (id, name) values (2, 'Costa');
insert into clients (id, name) values (3, 'Boots');
insert into clients (id, name) values (4, 'Nandos');
```

Statement for SQL Server 2016+:

```
SELECT 
   i.id, 
   i.title,
   [affectedclients] = STUFF(
      (
      SELECT CONCAT(', ', c.[name])
      FROM OPENJSON(i.affectedclients) WITH (id int '$') j
      LEFT JOIN clients c on c.id = j.id
      FOR XML PATH('')
      ), 1, 2, '')
FROM issues i
```

Statement for SQL Server 2017+:

```
SELECT i.id, i.title, STRING_AGG(c.name, ', ') AS affectedclients
FROM issues i
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(i.affectedclients) WITH (id int '$') j
LEFT JOIN clients c ON c.id = j.id
GROUP BY i.id, i.title
ORDER BY i.id, i.title
```

Results:

```
-----------------------------------------------
id  title                       affectedclients
-----------------------------------------------
1   Error when clicking save    Tesco, Costa
2   404 error on url            Boots
```